# virt-install causes Putty session to freeze

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt

Using Putty to log in to a remote CentOS 7 server, I am able to successfully create a CentOS 7 guest virtual machine in the CentOS 7 host.

However, the command causes the console to freeze and eventually time out, without giving any indication that it has successfully created the virtual machine.  I have to then log in again with a separate Putty session in order to confirm that the guest virtual machine has been created.

**What specific command(s) need to be typed in order to instruct the CentOS 7 host machine to create the CentOS 7 guest virtual machine in a way that gives meaningful result-reporting in the terminal without locking up?**  The command needs to produce meaningful feedback that can be integrated into a script afterwards.

---

**Complete Terminal Output:**

---

Here is the terminal log of the locked-up/timed-out Putty session resulting from my current `virt-install` syntax:

```
[root@remote-host ~]# virt-install --name centos7 --ram 2048 --disk path=/dev/mapper/centos-third,size=242 --vcpus 1 --os-type generic --os-variant generic --network bridge=virbr0 --graphics none --console pty,target_type=serial --cdrom /tmp/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso
WARNING  CDROM media does not print to the text console by default, so you likely will not see text install output. You might want to use --location. See the man page for examples of using --location with CDROM media

Starting install...
Creating domain...                                 |    0 B  00:00:00
Connected to domain centos7
Escape character is ^]
```

---

**Independent Validation in a SEPARATE Putty Session:**

---

After the above-documented Putty session timed out, I started another (separate) Putty session, and used `virsh` to discover that the first guest virtual machine had been successfully created, as follows:

```
[root@remote-host ~]# virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 5     centos7                        running

[root@remote-host ~]# virsh dominfo centos7
Id:             5
Name:           centos7
UUID:           some-very-long-string
OS Type:        hvm
State:          running
CPU(s):         1
CPU time:       1742.1s
Max memory:     2097152 KiB
Used memory:    2097152 KiB
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      disable
Managed save:   no
Security model: selinux
Security DOI:   0
Security label: system_u:system_r:svirt_t:s0:c654,c992 (enforcing)

[root@remote-host ~]# virsh vcpuinfo centos7
VCPU:           0
CPU:            2
State:          running
CPU time:       1839.3s
CPU Affinity:   yyyy

[root@remote-host ~]#
```

---

**Another Attempt:**

---

Next, I tried the suggestion from the error message above and opened up a separate (third) Putty session to run the following command to create a different guest virtual machine using `--location` instead of `--cdrom` so that console output can be printed, but I am getting the following error:

```
[root@remote-host ~]# virt-install --name centos7b --ram 2048 --disk path=/dev/mapper/centos-fourth,size=242 --vcpus 1 --os-type generic --os-variant generic --network bridge=virbr0 --graphics none --console pty,target_type=serial --location=/tmp/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso
ERROR    'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

**How can we change the commands above to provide meaningful feedback about success or failure of the `virt-install` command without having to wait until the session times out and start a separate session?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your virt-install is working just fine, but that you don't have access to the VM's console (text or gui) to perform the actual installation steps.  This means that your VM is up and running, but it is sitting at the first screen of the install awaiting input.

You can get around this by using a [Kickstart Installation with virt-install](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide/sect-Guest_virtual_machine_installation_overview-Creating_guests_with_virt_install.html#sect-Guest_virtual_machine_installation_overview-virt_install-Kickstart).

The [kickstart](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/chap-kickstart-installations.html) file tells the installer what you want so that you don't have to interactively enter that information.

I think you will probably want to use the `halt` (default), `shutdown` or `poweroff` kickstart command so that virt-install will exit when the install is complete.